# How can I control the vertical spacing of entries in an index

Tags: spacing, indexing

```
%
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\documentclass{book} %
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} %
\usepackage{titletoc} %\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[english]{babel} %
\usepackage{tikz} % tikz - essential
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % no apparent effect
\usepackage[utf8,latin1]{inputenx} %
\usepackage{txfonts} % 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=120mm,verbose,driver=none,showcrop, showframe]{geometry} % verbose,showcrop,showframe
\usepackage[a4,frame,center]{crop} %
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[unbalanced,indentunit=12pt]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm} %
%
\indexsetup{othercode=\normalsize}
%
\makeindex[program=makeindex,title=Index - poor vertical spacing,columns=2,options={-s my_index_book.ist}]
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CONTENT OF THE .ist file %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% headings_flag 1

% heading_prefix "\\vspace*{0.4cm}\\nopagebreak\n\\tikz\\node at (0pt,0pt)
% [rounded corners=3pt,draw=ThemeColor,fill=ThemeGrey,line width=1pt,inner sep=5pt]
% {\\parbox{\\linewidth-2\\fboxsep-2\\fboxrule-2pt}{\\hspace{3pt}\\large\\sffamily\\bfseries\\textcolor{black}
% {" heading_suffix "}}};\\vspace*{0.1cm}\\nopagebreak\n"

% delim_0 "\\dotfill"

% delim_1 "\\dotfill"

% delim_2 "\\dotfill"
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\definecolor{ThemeColor}{rgb}{0.45,0.00,0.45} %
\definecolor{ThemeGrey}{rgb}{0.93,0.93,0.93}

\begin{document}

% Sorry, don't know where the -2-2pt in heading of the index is coming from.
\noindent In the index that follows, I would like more space above word "apricot".

\index{apples!aaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
\index{apples!aaaaaaaaaaaaab}
\index{apples!aaaaaaaaaaaaac}
\index{apples!aaaaaaaaaaaaad}
\index{apricots!aaaaaaaaaaad}
\index{apricots!aaaaaaaaaaaae}
\index{apricots!aaaaaaaaaaaaf}
\index{apricots!aaaaaaaaaaaag}
\index{oranges!aaaaaaaaaaaag}
\index{oranges!aaaaaaaaaaaah}
\index{oranges!aaaaaaaaaaaak}
\index{oranges!aaaaaaaaaaaaz}
\index{oranges!aaaaaaaaaaaaz}
\index{oranges!aaaaaaaaaaaay}
\index{oranges!aaaaaaaaaaaay}
\index{oranges!aaaaaaaaaaaay}
\index{oranges!aaaaaaaaaaaar}
\index{oranges!aaaaaaaaaaaas}
\index{oranges!aaaaaaaaaaaad}
\index{oranges!aaaaaaaaaaaae}

\vspace{12pt}
\noindent Would like to control the vertical spacing (increase) above the word "apricot" in the index.

\printindex %

\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, the problem is that all entries in the finished index file are spaced (pretty much) equally.  I want each primary entry: say the apricots to have a larger separation BEFORE its entry to clear the previous batch which concerned the apples.

Comment: Regarding the `-2-2pt` string that appears in the labels: In the code of the `ist` file, you have to write `...\\parbox{\\dimexpr\\linewidth...`. The `\dimexpr` command is missing.

Comment: `amsmath` has nothing to do with the index you've described -- there is no math in any of the entries.  i've removed that tag and changed the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way would be to run `makeindex` with an index style file (`.ist`) that contains something like:

```
item_0 "\n\\vspace{10pt}\\item "
```

Another way is to patch the environment `theindex` with:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\theindex}{\let\item\@idxitem}{\def\item{\vspace{10pt}\@idxitem}}{}{ERROR}
```

Of course you can adapt the `10pt` to your taste.

Comment: headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\vspace*{0.4cm}\\nopagebreak\n\\tikz\\node at (0pt,0pt)
[rounded corners=3pt,draw=ThemeColor,fill=ThemeGrey,line width=1pt,inner sep=5pt]
{\\parbox{\\dimexpr\\linewidth-2\\fboxsep-2\\fboxrule-2pt}{\\hspace{3pt}\\large\\sffamily\\bfseries\\textcolor{black}
{" heading_suffix "}}};\\vspace*{0.1cm}\\nopagebreak\n"
item_0 " \n\\vspace{8pt}\\item "
item_1 " \n\\vspace{-1pt}\\item "
delim_0 " \\dotfill "
delim_1 " \\dotfill "

Comment: Piet van Oostrum Many thanks for that.  Revised the .ist file as above.  Good, except that the indent of the secondary entries is lost after the first line.

Comment: Make that: `item_1 " \n\\vspace{-1pt}\\subitem "` for indentation (and `\\subsubitem` for the next level.

Comment: Piet  Many, many thanks - perfect solution.  However, there is no tick for me to accept this solution (the first).